# UIScrollView contentOffset animates to another point

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uiscrollview

Good day,
I'm facing a wired behavior in a UIScrollView here. I'm implementing a custom circular UIScrollView and in a point I've to set the origin of the scroll view to a point

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)
```

After that I change the content offset using animation to a specific point

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: point, y: 0), animated: true)
```

The problem is that although point is correct (ex. 400) scrollview sometimes jumps to another point so code like the following should print 10 if point = 10 but sometimes it prints other values.

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: point, y: 0), animated: true)                        
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                        print("Current x: \(self.tabsScrollView.contentOffset.x)")})
```

Although I made sure that no other animation was in progress.

I found that someone was suggesting something like that

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
                        self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = point
                    })
```

And surprisingly it did work, but not animated like default.
Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by **After that I change teh content offset using animation to a specific point so user cannot notice that ScrollView has been jump instantly before it actually animates**  ?

Comment: I removed that part as it may be misleading, it it clear now?